# How do I plot flights data from nycflights13 so that x=airlines, y = dep_delay?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to plot x = airlines, y = dep_delay, I get an error message.

My hypothesis is that delays are caused by the inefficiency of the airlines above and beyond any other factors. I simply want to plot these two variables, I get an error message.

I try this code but it doesn't work.

```
ggplot(data = flights, mapping = aes(x = airlines, y= dep_delay)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)



ggplot(data = flights, mapping = aes(x = airlines, y = dep_delay)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (336776): x

Comment: Airlines is a data set. I think you need carrier instead. Use this: `ggplot(data = flights, mapping = aes(x = carrier, y= dep_delay))+........`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two "+" instead of a single "+" sign